# which is better: a string representing a filename or a FileName class?

Tags: string, class, language-agnostic

The advantage of the class is that it can automatically filter bad strings on assignment/construction.  It also makes it so you are absolutely sure you are dealing with a filename, not just a string that is *SUPPOSED* to represent a filename.

The problem with the class is that, where is the limit?  Would we end up creating a huge assortment of unnecessary classes?  For instance, some string should only be between x and y characters.  Should I make a class for those?

What about a class for URLs?  Or a class for only uppercase strings?  Where does one draw the line?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

it depends on the context.  in most applications you wouldn't bother, for the reasons you give, and also because the APIs that you're working with expect file names to be strings anyway (and is there any advantage in checking a valid file name?  maybe you would see a suitable error when you try to use it, and that code, in the system library, is going to adapt to different platforms, which you may not know about or be testing on...).

however, i can imagine a specialised application or library where it might be important to know the difference between a directory and a file (classes can mark the distinction at the type level), or where you need lots of file-related information (the class would be a good place to collect this) or high performance when doing certain operations on file names (the class could help with performance by caching results), etc etc.

so the best design is going to depend on exactly what you are doing.  is it critical for your system to have only upper-case strings?  aren't URLs already in the network library you are using?  context is everything...

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you're saying about checking the validity of the filename.  At least in C#, there is a way of finding out what the system invalid characters are, so if one were to be running on a different OS, assuming that that OS exposes those invalid characters to the language, it would be easy to check.  The code itself is platform-independent.  I guess I was thinking it would be generally good to put it in a class, that way when you pass it as a parameter, you KNOW it represents a valid filename, regardless of who's been manipulating it.

Comment: ok, so for c# then you would take that into account.  that is what i mean by *context*.

Answer (score 0):

Try thinking in terms of objects rather than simply strings. What does the string represent? If it represents something more than a word or phrase than a class probably makes sense.

Rather than define a FileName class I'd define a File class to represent the actual file. The FileName would simply be a property of that class (you could put your filename validation in the class then).  It would also provide you the opportunity to build in useful related properties and methods like Open(), Write(), Close(), Read(), PathName, etc.

Similarly a class for Urls makes sense because there are other details you will probably want to extract from the string. For example: Hostname, Port, QueryString. By making it a class you can bundle all of this functionality in one spot.

Comment: Similarly to the url, a filename class would allow support for getting its components, like the server (if it's not local), path, name, full path, filetype, etc.  The reason I didn't want to put it in a file class is that, imo, a file represents something that exists on disk.  A filename may not exist as a file on disk.  Also, why not break it up into it's components?  Like a webpage has a url, which itself has a hostname etc.